# How to increase hit area of a radio button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, radio-button

As asked above how can I increase the hit area of a radio button control in asp.net? For example I have a 200 x 200px div that I would like to make the hit area for the radio button. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) for the radio button.

See [this](http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/3b-iii-labels-radio.html) example.